# docker container files owner

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have multiple containers running and I don't know how to make some of them be under one user or one group. Because on the host I have installed samba for access from a windows pc, so that I can edit the files. But I have a problem because when the files are shared from the containers they share the files with a user from the container, and my user does not have the group rights to edit them because they do not exist on the host. I think that I can edit them with the root user, but for security reasons I don't want that user to be active.
[printscreen user:999](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsKlT.png)
[printscreen user:postmaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxCuW.png)

Comment: How are files shared from the container? Why is Samba mentioned? Your post has two screenshots. What are they showing? Edit your post with better details.

Comment: But both images have usernames inside the containers by default. If I change the users with WINSCP and add the user I'm working with, I can change the files from the host, but after restarting the host, the owner of the files reverts back to the default containers. When I try to edit a file, I get a "I don't have permissions" message because the file containers add their user.

Comment: " I think that I can edit them with the root user, but for security reasons I don't want that user to be active" agreed!  `root` completely avoids all security, and as the owner of these resources, *you want security*.  In linux users boil down to user  and group ID, an integer number, and so your problem is aligning the IDs in your docker containers with the IDs in the host system.  "on the host I have installed samba for access from a windows pc, so that I can edit the files" usually folks focus more on *distributing* files to the servers once they develop locally.